# スマホ(iOS/Android)で見る場合にポートレート表示(縦表示)固定にするWebサイト側の設定方法

Tags: ios, android, css

普通のWebサイトを作成しています。それのスマホでの見え方なのですが、PCやタブレットで見る場合は問題無いのですが、スマホ(iOS/Android)で見る場合に、
スマホ自体の画面表示回転/非回転設定にかかわらず常に「ポートレート表示(縦表示)」となる、すなわち「ポートレート表示(縦表示)」でしか表示されないようなWeb側の設定を知りたいのです。
ネットを調べてみたのですが、ランドスケープとポートレートを切り替えるCSSはあるのですが、ポートレート表示(縦表示)固定にする方法が見つかりません。どなたかご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

Screen Orientation API の [`lock()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock) で可能なようです。ただし、Chromium 系のブラウザでしか使えないようですね。

Comment: そうでしたか。Safariに対応されていなければ使いずらいですね。了解致しました。コメントありがとうございました。